# How do I check 'git status' for some sub folders?

Tags: git, command-line, package

We are using a custom version of composer for our package manager.

Every package we add to our project is actually a `.git` repo.
Naturally, those folders (/Vendor/packages/) are ignored by the parent repo and when I write `git status` it only shows the current repo's status.

Is there way to check status of the .git repos under my project.
I'm looking for something like `git submodule foreach status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find` sub-directories in `Vendor/packages` and execute `git status` on each one of them.

`find Vendor/packages -type d -maxdepth 1 -print -exec sh -c '(echo {} && cd {} && git status && echo)' \;`

*This is with the assumption that all folders under Vendor/packages are git repos by themselves.*

Comment: Too complicated. use the single line solution in the answer below.

Comment: @CodeWizard: Would git submodules work if folders under vendors system, are not git submodules, just git repos which are not linked to the parent git repo in any manner?

Comment: You cant have repo inside repo if its not submodule. git will not work correctly.

Comment: This worked but I agree that it is a little bit complicated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status .
```

will show you the status of the file of the current folder and its sub folders but not to submodules.

To list changes under submodules you will have to use the below line:

```
# use the build in submodule foreach option
git submodule foreach --recursive git diff --name-status
```

> **`git submodule foreach`** [--recursive] 
>   Evaluates an arbitrary shell command **in each checked out submodule**.
>
> If `--recursive` is given, submodules are traversed **recursively** (i.e. the given shell command is evaluated in nested submodules as well).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, we are not using git's submodule feature. The packages are downloaded via _composer_ but not added to the parent repo as submodules. They are just ignored folders by the parent repo.

Comment: So you have ignored folders which you want to check the status for them? If they are ignored than all the files are untracked. what diff do you expect to find?

Comment: While working on a project I sometimes find myself editing code in a package. I sometimes move my changes to the original repo and sometimes push directly from the project repo. Both of them has the same remote by the way. I am not sure if it is good practice though.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
git status directory_path
```

for ex

```
git status upload/
```